# Tabletop JS - Create new HTML page when new row is inserted?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, google-sheets, tabletop.js

Just as the title asks, is that possible? Or is there anything I can do to make that happen?

I'm creating a website that grabs information from a google sheet as live content to the website. Is there a way I can make it create a new page from my page template for when a new row is inserted?

Comment: How are you creating an entirely new page when a row is inserted? Are you asking if you can create a new template or a new element?

Comment: @QTRay I'm asking how I can create a new page using my template but with the information of the new row

Comment: I think you're looking for something similar to this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-google-sheets-db

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can,
You can use the Google Sheets script.
But for that, you might need a middleware backend program.

Please follow this google guide to create the project

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

After you create a script,
Please set the trigger to "Change". (This will automatically fire your app method.)

Inside the function, you can call API to your web server. (If you just have a static website you will need a backend program as well.)